# Success handler and failure handler not called spring-security

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-oauth2

I am trying to save data upon token success or failure, but my success and failure handlers not getting called by Spring.

I already added the `CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler` and `CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler`, but they aren't being called.

This my `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class Authentication extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    @Autowired
    private BcaAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;
    @Autowired
    private CustomLdapAuthProvider ldapProvider;
    @Autowired
    private LoginAttemptsService loginAttemptsService;
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    @Autowired
    private BcaAuthenticationProviderLocal authenticationProviderLocal;

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationSuccessHandler customAuthenticationSuccessHandler(){
        CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler customAuthenticationSuccessHandler = new CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
        customAuthenticationSuccessHandler.setLoginAttemptsService(loginAttemptsService);
//      customAuthenticationSuccessHandler.setDefaultTargetUrl(defaultTargetUrl);
        customAuthenticationSuccessHandler.setUserService(userService);
        return customAuthenticationSuccessHandler;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationFailureHandler customAuthenticationFailureHandler() {
        CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler customAuthenticationFailureHandler = new CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler();
        customAuthenticationFailureHandler.setLoginAttemptsService(loginAttemptsService);
        customAuthenticationFailureHandler.setUserService(userService);
        return customAuthenticationFailureHandler;
    }


    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder()
    {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure (AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception
    {

//      auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider); // bca ldap webservice

//      auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProviderLocal); //local ldap webservice

        auth            
            .userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder()); // username password

//      auth.ldapAuthentication()
//          .userSearchFilter("(uid={0})")
//          .userSearchBase("dc=example,dc=com")
//          .groupSearchBase("dc=example,dc=com")
//          .userDnPatterns("uid={0}")
//          .contextSource()
//          .url("ldap://ldap.forumsys.com:389");

        /*LDAP AUTHENTITICATION*/
//      auth.authenticationProvider(ldapProvider);

    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean () throws Exception
    {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure (HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/oauth/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/swagger**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET).permitAll().anyRequest()
                .authenticated().and().formLogin().permitAll()
                .successHandler(customAuthenticationSuccessHandler())
                .failureHandler(customAuthenticationFailureHandler());
//      http.addFilterAfter(
//                new CustomFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }


}
```

This is my `CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler`:

```
public class CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler {

    private UserService userService;

    public void setUserService(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    private LoginAttemptsService loginAttemptsService;

    public LoginAttemptsService getLoginAttemptsService() {
        return loginAttemptsService;
    }

    public void setLoginAttemptsService(LoginAttemptsService loginAttemptsService) {
        this.loginAttemptsService = loginAttemptsService;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {
        System.out.println("THIS IS FAIL");
        Account user = userService.findByUsername(request.getParameter("username"));
        loginAttemptsService.InfoUser(user, false);

        super.onAuthenticationFailure(request, response, exception);
    }
}
```

And this is my `CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler`:

```
public class CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    private UserService userService;

    public void setUserService(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    private LoginAttemptsService loginAttemptsService;

    public LoginAttemptsService getLoginAttemptsService() {
        return loginAttemptsService;
    }

    public void setLoginAttemptsService(LoginAttemptsService loginAttemptsService) {
        this.loginAttemptsService = loginAttemptsService;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {

        System.out.println("THIS SUCCESS");
        Account user = userService.findByUsername(authentication.getName());
        loginAttemptsService.InfoUser(user, true);

        super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
    }

}
```

What can I do so that when someone attempts to obtain an OAuth token, the success or failure will be persisted to a database?

Comment: What happens when authentication via the form fails?

Comment: is just wanna check if someone call my oauth/token, and it will be save to my database, when if fail i'll save it as failure access, so i can track every call in my oauth token

Comment: but you configured it as: http.antMatchers("/oauth/**").permitAll()... there is no authentication check for /oauth/token

Comment: i already solve this, i use event listener to check user call my token